# Is there a way to get the recipients email using graph API?

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I want to get the toRecipient properties from the graph API response. I'm trying to use the below code which I wrote.

```
var GetToEmail = await graphClient.Users[$"{_Email}"].MailFolders["Inbox"]
                        .ChildFolders[$"{SubFolderId1}"]
                        .ChildFolders[$"{SubFolderId2}"]
                        .Messages[$"{MessageID}"]
                        .Request()
                        /*.Select(eml => new
                        {
                            eml.Id,
                            eml.From,
                            eml.ToRecipients
                        })*/
                        .GetAsync();

            foreach (var recipient in GetToEmail.ToRecipients)
            {
                WriteLogClass.WriteToLog(3, $"{recipient}");
            }
```

The problem is "ToRecipient" property shows up as . It doesn't support `GetToEmail.ToRecipients.EmailAddress.Address`. I tried graph explorer to see the JSON response which looks like the one below.

```
{
    "sender": {
        "emailAddress": {
            "name": "CTDS Servicedesk",
            "address": "ctds.servicedesk@kghcustoms.com"
        }
    },
    "from": {
        "emailAddress": {
            "name": "CTDS Servicedesk",
            "address": "ctds.servicedesk@kghcustoms.com"
        }
    },
    "toRecipients": [
        {
            "emailAddress": {
                "name": "Sandaruwan Samaraweera",
                "address": "sandaruwan.s@pro-account.lk"
            }
        }
    ],
    "ccRecipients": [],
    "bccRecipients": [],
    "replyTo": [],
    "flag": {
        "flagStatus": "notFlagged"
    }
}
```

As you can see it does contain the needed details I just can't get my head around how to retrieve it. I know how to get sender and from details but I can't use the same method on toRecipient. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is `ToRecipients` a list? That's what it looks like in the JSON so .`ToString` on a list what give the content of the list.

Comment: `toRecipients` is a collection, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/message?view=graph-rest-1.0#:~:text=of%20the%20message.-,toRecipients,The%20To%3A%20recipients%20for%20the%20message.,-uniqueBody

Comment: @PeterSmith tried to loop it using `foreach` but it still can't get it to show the data it just says `Microsoft.Graph.Recipient`. I'm new to graph and C#.

Comment: The examples on the Microsoft site give a nice example on how to do that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/collections

Comment: Can you show the `foreach` code you are using

Comment: @PeterSmith I changed the code to the one with the `foreach`. I'm using function to write tthe to a log thats what `WriteLogClass.WriteToLog` does.

Comment: `recipient ` in your loop is a structure; you then need to select the field(s)

Comment: @PeterSmith I think I found the method can you please look at it and verify if what I'm doing correct or not. `foreach (var recipient in GetToEmail.ToRecipients.Select(x => x.EmailAddress.Address))`

Comment: Have you tried it - does it work; it looks as if it should. You could also do that within the loop so that you have the option of getting other fields

Comment: @PeterSmith It does work but it seems to pick the entire set. If there's more than 1 recipient it's select both. I just want to get the emails ending with "efakturamottak.no". Can you show me how can I do this with in the loop if possible.

Comment: Look at `Contains("efakturamottak.no")`

Comment: @PeterSmith I came up with the below solution.
```foreach (var recipient in GetToEmail.ToRecipients.Select(x => x.EmailAddress))
                {
                    Regex SelectEmails = new Regex(@"^.+@efakturamottak.no$");
                    if (SelectEmails.IsMatch(recipient.Address))
                    {
                        WriteLogClass.WriteToLog(3, $"Email recipiant from XML -> {recipient.Address}");
                    }
                }```

using `.Contsins` or `EndsWith` gave `True` or `False`.