# Change email address in replyto or replyall

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

We are using Microsoft Graph API to send and receive emails. Just like outlook, during a reply is composed, we want to change, remove or add new recipients. However, MS graph api of [replyall](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-replyall?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) or [reply](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-reply?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) does not allow changing any email address.

How can we achieve this functionality using MS Graph API ?

Comment: hi, perhaps set the recipients like that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73508783/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-recipients-email-using-graph-api

Comment: Thanks for reply. Your link about is reading the address... API is not allowing to write/update the address while replyTo

Comment: In my case, I was able to change the mail addresses but the mail was not being detected as a reply. I removed the subject parameter from the request and it works as expected now.

Answer (score 0):

You should use create-reply endpoint https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-createreply?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

That will create a draft reply message (and return the Id for that) that you can then patch any way you want including updating the recipient addresses and replyto then you send that draft message.